# How to put animated image's in order decided randomly

Tags: java, swing

I try to make my own simple game with pairs of images that player try to guess position of same ones and I have no clue how to have 2 same bufferedimages that are animated put on frame in random position that not extends frame size and what need to be done to images to dont put them on same x and y that previous ones. Can collision system do the work and remove the image put on similiar x and y or is there better solutions.

What I got for now [is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5UJwc.png) full one image animated that can be covered by the 
covering image.

What I did to achieve this.

```
public Rozmiar(Game game, Textures tex) {
    this.game = game;
    this.tex = tex;

    for (int x = 128; x < (Game.WIDTH * Game.SCALE - 128); x += 128) {
        for (int y = 96; y < (Game.HEIGHT * Game.SCALE - 96); y += 128) {
            addOdkryte(new Odkryte(x, y, tex));
        }
    }
}




public void addOdkryte(Odkryte block) {
    os.add(block);
}





package com.game.src.main;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class Odkryte {

private double x;
private double y;

private Textures tex;
Animation anim;
Animation anim1;
private int counter;

public Odkryte(double x, double y, Textures tex) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.tex = tex;

    anim = new Animation(3, tex.odkimg1px128[0], tex.odkimg1px128[1], tex.odkimg1px128[2], tex.odkimg1px128[3],
            tex.odkimg1px128[4], tex.odkimg1px128[5], tex.odkimg1px128[6], tex.odkimg1px128[7], tex.odkimg1px128[8],
            tex.odkimg1px128[9]);
}

public void tick() {
    anim.runAnimation();
}

public void render(Graphics g) {
    anim.drawAnimation(g, x, y, 0);
}
```

}

Comment: what is the expect output? Do you have a screenshot of that? What is Odkryte and addOdkryte? Can you post code for those?

Answer (score 1):

1. Add the pairs of images to an ArrayList
2. Use the Collections.shuffle(...) method on the ArrayList to randomize the images
3. Iterate through the ArrayList and add each image to the frame.